# split a sentence at an entered string and use the second splitted part

Tags: python, split

My target is to make the user put the question and his MCQs answers and get the most right answer.
I copied the text that will be used to search the question in into a string called Text and then it will search for the most sentence that will have most common words between the text sentences and the question words, and then he will compare the answers with the sentence to choose only one.

```
text="pla pla pla pla pla. pla pla pla pla pla. pla pla pla. pla pla pla." 
for line in sentences:
    for word in Mylist:
         if word in line:
                k=k+1       
                listed.append(line)
c = Counter(listed)
z=[x[0] for x in c.most_common(1)] ##the sentence that has most common question's words
    for j in z: # to make the sentence string not element in list
        for ans in ListOfans: #check each answers of the MCqs answers
            for word in ans.split():
                 if word in j:
                    MostAns.append(ans) # put the answers found in the sentence
d=Counter(MostAns)                        
p=[x[0] for x in d.most_common(1)]
print(p) #display the answer
```

My problem is if all the answers are in the sentence it gives me wrong answer, I thinked of splitting the sentence at the question's words then check the first answer come after the split mostly will be the right answer
for example if the sentence ("I played tennis then ate cake" and the question " what you played?" and the choices are: tennis or cake ) it will split ate played as this is the common word between the sentence and the question, then check the first choice after the split, it will find Tennis, so this is the answer,
I don't know how to split the sentence at the last common word and check the answer next?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: What are `sentences` and `Mylist`? Why doesn't the code ever use `text`?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to get this simple comparison function to perform AI. Ad hoc rules like you describe won't work very reliably.